# Imported Alembic (Animated mesh) I need it to have same # of vertices for fluid sim

Tags: mesh, vertices, fluid-simulation

I am working on a project where I plan to have multiple fluid sims running, I am having problems with my imported animated mesh, where each frame has different number of vertices. (This has previously been exported as alembic) then reimported, so I can start on fluid sim #2

I am trying to create the 2nd fluid sim and want the first simulation(Imported Animated Mesh) to be an obstacle so the new mesh kind of flows/moves with it.

The problem is when using the 1st imported mesh as the obstacle with option export animated mesh for calculations. Blender tells me that the exported mesh,  must have the same number of vertices for each frame.

I have tried the shrinkwrap modifier on a cube outside the animated mesh and it doesnt give me the best results. it stretches the cube over the fluid but doesnt really fill in voids etc...

is there a way to rebuild the mesh to be the same number of vertices for each frame?
such as using decimate in a way it deletes only a few vertices to make the count the same for each frame?

cheers
Shaun

Comment: I'm strongly interrested by a tip on it too.
How to get a fixed polycount on meshes with alembic export?